# Is there any difference between jQuery offset and position method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any difference between position and the offset method. Because when I will do `console.log()`, both are returning an object, having two property top and left. My doubt is, when we will use offset and when the position method or they both are do same thing.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Difference between jQuery position and offset method</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <button id='btnOne'>click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightgray;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnOne').on('click', function(){
        var offset = $('.box').offset();
        var position = $('.box').position();
        console.log(offset, position);
    });
});
```

and here is the jsbin link - 
http://jsbin.com/qibov/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Yes there's a difference, and it is detailed in the documentation, which is the first place you should look. [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) ... [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Offset() *measures* from screen top/left, Position() measures from parent's top/left. (I could be wrong)

**proof**

**CSS**

```
.box{ width: 100px; height: 100px; background: lightgray; margin-bottom: 10px; }
#cntnr{position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;}
```

**HTML**
    `<div id="cntnr">
    <div class='box'></div>
</div>
<button id='btnOne'>click</button>`

**JavaScript**

```
//same
```

**result**

```
Object { top=100, left=100} Object { top=0, left=0}
```

putting the `.box` inside a container doesn't change it's `position` but changes it's `offset`;

Comment: yes, i got the difference, when you will change the container position, that time, it's returning different value.

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery documentation for `.offset()`:

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the document. Contrast this with .position(), which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent. When positioning a new element on top of an existing one for global manipulation (in particular, for implementing drag-and-drop), .offset() is more useful.

https://api.jquery.com/offset/